# Формат при записи списка в .txt не работает

Tags: python-3.6

Нужно записать данные в файл в виде таблицы. Код:

```
x = open(s,'w')  
n=[6,8,8,8]  
for i in l:  
    if i[3][-1]=='\n':
        i[3]=i[3][:-1]
m=[max(len(l[0][i])+1,len(l[1][i])+1,len(l[2][i])+1,len(l[3][i])+1,n[i]) for i in range(len(l[0]))]
print('{:{}}{:{}}{:{}}{:{}}'.format('Товар',m[0],'За 2015',m[1],'За 2016',m[2],'За 2017',m[3]),file=x)
for i in range(len(l[0])):
    print('{:{}}{:{}}{:{}}{:{}}'.format(l[i][0],m[0],l[i][1],m[1],l[i][2],m[2],l[i][3],m[3]),file=x)
x.close()
```

При выводе в питон (без параметра file=x) формат сохранен, в отличие от .txt файла

[image]
[image]

Comment: попробуйте одинаковый шрифт выставить в консоли и редакторе (или просто в консоль выведите файл: `type table.txt` или `cat table.txt`)

Comment: Скорее всего в текстовом редакторе у вас не моноширинный шрифт настроен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В текстовом редакторе нужно поставить моноширинный шрифт (например, Courier)